# In codeigniter view page the data is not displaying from database

Tags: codeigniter

I am not getting the result in view page but its displaying while i am printing in controller. Its working perfect in my local but its not working in server. Please help me to get solution for this.

Comment: please add your code trials and error you getting, read [mcve]

Comment: Add your code trials

Comment: I think you are missing that data to pass to the view. Share some your code where you are passing data to view in controller. and how you are accessing data in view.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your code in view page properly, As my experience any loop or condition is not closed in your code.
In localhost error is showing but code is execute after that error but on server code is not execute after error in code